# How to delete a broken data in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I have a file that gets statistic data of an upload script. This is what I get.

```
    0K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........   4% 72.83 KiB/s
  470K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........   9% 84.67 KiB/s
 1088K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  15% 91.78 KiB/s
 1708K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  20% 90.17 KiB/s
  1250K .......... .......... ....   5% 85.29 KiB/s
  6150K .........  10% 64.32 KiB/s
  8350K .......... .......... ........... .......... .....  15% 55.12 KiB/s
...==> STOR test10.zip ... ....  20% 59.38 KiB/s
    0K ................. .......... ... ............. ............. ............  25% 66.21 KiB/s
 2845K ...... .......... ........... .............. . ................... ...   4% 32.62 KiB/s
  464K ................ ... ..................  29% 59.62 KiB/s
 3371K .. ................ ....... ...... ................ ....... ........... ......   8% 38.75 KiB/s
  963K ............ ................ ....  34% 51.58 KiB/s
2253K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  24% 99.92 KiB/s
 2787K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  29% 92.12 KiB/s
 3291K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  33% 84.42 KiB/s
 3821K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  38% 75.88 KiB/s
 4342K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  43% 73.12 KiB/s
```

Some have broken data that is caused by internet problems.
So what I want is to remove those broken data and it will look like this:

```
    0K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........   4% 72.83 KiB/s
  470K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........   9% 84.67 KiB/s
 1088K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  15% 91.78 KiB/s
 1708K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  20% 90.17 KiB/s
 2253K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  24% 99.92 KiB/s
 2787K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  29% 92.12 KiB/s
 3291K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  33% 84.42 KiB/s
 3821K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  38% 75.88 KiB/s
 4342K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  43% 73.12 KiB/s
```

*NOTE: Not all the time, the data is the same of the example above.*

Comment: Each valid data item is follows a specific pattern. Define that pattern as a regular expression. Read the received data and match each line against the patten. Discard whatever doesn't match. Retain whatever matches. Consolidate the retained data at the end to get the filtered non-broken data.

Comment: @AndrewGuy Hello, I extracted that data in python using regex, and I'm trying to figure out how to solve that problem but I find it difficult to solve.

Comment: @Sharad Hi there, I'm getting your point. It's just not clear for me how to code it. So tell me if I'm wrong with my idea, that I need to store the pattern into a variable?

Comment: @CCISIT If you used regex to get your initial data, it may help to post this regex. It may be a simple alteration to your pattern to exclude your unwanted data. But you'll get much less help if you're asking people to just write a full solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

**One way to do this:**

```
$ cat foo.py
data = '''
    0K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........   4% 72.83 KiB/s
  470K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........   9% 84.67 KiB/s
 1088K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  15% 91.78 KiB/s
 1708K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  20% 90.17 KiB/s
  1250K .......... .......... ....   5% 85.29 KiB/s
  6150K .........  10% 64.32 KiB/s
  8350K .......... .......... ........... .......... .....  15% 55.12 KiB/s
...==> STOR test10.zip ... ....  20% 59.38 KiB/s
    0K ................. .......... ... ............. ............. ............  25% 66.21 KiB/s
 2845K ...... .......... ........... .............. . ................... ...   4% 32.62 KiB/s
  464K ................ ... ..................  29% 59.62 KiB/s
 3371K .. ................ ....... ...... ................ ....... ........... ......   8% 38.75 KiB/s
  963K ............ ................ ....  34% 51.58 KiB/s
2253K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  24% 99.92 KiB/s
 2787K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  29% 92.12 KiB/s
 3291K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  33% 84.42 KiB/s
 3821K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  38% 75.88 KiB/s
 4342K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  43% 73.12 KiB/s
'''

import re
pattern = r".*\d+K\s+(\.{10}\s){5}\s*\d+%\s+\d+\.\d+\s+KiB\/s.*"

for line in data.split('\n'):
    if re.match(pattern, line) is not None:
        print(line)
$
```

**Execution result:**

```
$ python foo.py
    0K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........   4% 72.83 KiB/s
  470K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........   9% 84.67 KiB/s
 1088K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  15% 91.78 KiB/s
 1708K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  20% 90.17 KiB/s
2253K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  24% 99.92 KiB/s
 2787K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  29% 92.12 KiB/s
 3291K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  33% 84.42 KiB/s
 3821K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  38% 75.88 KiB/s
 4342K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  43% 73.12 KiB/s
$
```